# Create .new file from filelist

Tags: linux, bash, testing, copy, diff

I've been searching all over the web for a .sh script to do this but i didn't find any.

In this moment i have a script that will create a file list with the find command.
This file list is used with copy to replicate them on another folder and everything works well.

Now i want to create a script file that will take the file list and perform the following test:
- If the file doesn't exist on destination, copy the file.
- If the file exists on the destination and it's the same of the source, don't do anyhing.
- If the file exists on the destination and it's different from the source, copy it and change it's extension to .new

This is the script that will create the file list:

```
# File source to copy text files
find /home/repo/source -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.inf' -o -name '*.xml' > ../copy-from.txt
sed -i 's/ /\\ /g' ../copy-from.txt

# File destination to copy text files
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.inf' -o -name '*.xml' > ../copy-to.txt
sed -i 's/ /\\ /g' ../copy-to.txt
sed -i 's/\(.\{2\}\)//' ../copy-to.txt

# Merge source and destination files and add cp command
paste ../copy-from.txt ../copy-to.txt > ../copy.sh
rm ../copy-from.txt ../copy-to.txt
sed -i 's/^/cp /' ../copy.sh
```

Hope someone can point me to the right path or provide a script that will do what i am looking for.

Regards

Comment: It's called `rsync` surely?

Comment: i've looked to rsync and i don't see how rsync can create .new files if they are newer.

Comment: Important note: I want the script create .new files, not overwrite the existing ones.

Comment: What happens if a file has extension `.new` and when you try to copy it there is already a file with the same name in the destination? You want to _change_ the extension to `.new`, but it's already `.new`, so changing it will have no effect.

Comment: If there is already a file with extension .new, i don't mind to replace it.

Comment: The idea is, for later, verifiy the differences between the normal and .new file and integrate the changes if i want them.
Because we are handling with config files which have been already modified, i don't want to replace them with new original files.
Think like the apache config file.
When you update apache, this get a new up-to-date config, but you don't want to replace the config right away but later after checking the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you might have to use a tool such as `git`. You could then use two repositories and inspect commits before you pull/merge from the other repository.

If you insist on doing it in way similar to the one you describe, here's a small bash script that does that. It does everything in a single step, i.e. no temporary files with the list of files to be copied are generated, it simply finds all new/changed files in the source directory and copies them over to the destination directory, adding a `.new` suffix if necessary.

```
src='/path/to/source/dir'
dst='/path/to/destination/dir'
find "$src" -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.inf' -o -name '*.xml' \) -printf '%P\0' |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        if [[ ! -e "$dst/$file" ]]; then
            cp -a -- "$src/$file" "$dst/$file"
        elif ! cmp --silent "$src/$file" "$dst/$file"; then
            cp -a -- "$src/$file" "$dst/$file.new"
        fi
    done
```

It uses `cmp` to figure out if two files are identical. This means that it might be slow if the files involved are big, as it might have to read the entire file. It should be fine for small config files though. Of course, this being a shell script, it might be slow if you have a lot of files as it invokes external programs.

Comment: Thanks for the script.
Effectively, i don't want to create a git repo locally for sync.

And when i run that script, i get this:

`# /home/repo/update.sh
/home/repo/update.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
find: `/home/repo/sources\r': No such file or directory
/home/repo/update.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
/home/repo/update.sh: line 7: `        elif ! cmp --silent "$src/$file" "$d't/$file"; then
#`

Comment: Are you sure that you pasted the file correctly? It appears that a windows machine was involved and messed up the line breaks. Convert them to unix line breaks (LF, not CRLF) before you run it. There's a handy command line program that can do that called `dos2unix`.